# how to store the contents of an arraylist in one column of table in sqlite database in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am having an arraylist  of strings. I needt to store that arraylist in the 1 column of database.
How can I do that?

Comment: Is it that you don't know how to traverse the arraylist, or that you don't know how to store data to a database, or is it that you want a single sql call do do the storage (which doesnt exist without a bit of manual coding)?

Comment: @mah: you forgot "or all of the above".

Answer (score -2, accepted):

take a String, append arraylist's index string with the help of loop

```
String all="";
for(int i=0;i<arraylist.lenght;i++)
{ 
    all=all+" "+ arraylist.get(i).tostring;
}
```

now store "all" in your DB field, only the problem with this is **SIZE**,
hope you got what i meant

Answer (score 0):

You can consider serializing an object into `byte[]` and saving it in your DB as a `BLOB` or going further encoding it in `Base64` and saving as a `TEXT`. I'm not sure that any of these two are a good way to save your `ArrayList` - I'm just pointing options.

You might also consider creating other table and creating relation between them. There is a good pratice in databases called [First Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

Comment: This is an old answer but I'd like to say that SQLite is a relational DB. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite

Comment: Please explain how and why SQLite is not a relational database?

Comment: @OMG-1 I'm not entirely sure why I wrote that, it was quite some time ago. If I recall correctly I think I might have been using a version of the library at the time which was not supporting relations explicitly, meaning via foreign keys. I was using SQLite in the Android context and on that platform the ability to have FK was added in API version 8 or 11. (Did quick research on my phone) Corrected, thanks!