# How to save byte array ( byte [] ) in SQLite table?

Tags: android, sqlite

How to save byte array ( byte [] ) in SQLite table ? What type column needs to be, can someone show me create/insert string ?

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191136/how-to-store-and-retrieve-a-byte-array-image-data-to-and-from-a-sqlite-databas

Comment: Consider also this answer, since it is not a good practice to make such things. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131340/how-to-store-the-contents-of-an-arraylist-in-one-column-of-table-in-sqlite-datab/7131651#7131651

Comment: you can see this topic :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280105/sqlite-how-to-declare-as-byte-array